# In my case, i want to make a multiple menu using if statement. How can i make the other if statement work for another menu?

Tags: php, html

I've made one menu work here, the other is doesn't work. I want to make both menu accessible either the "persegi" or the "persegi panjang"

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="kirikolom">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['menu']))
    {
        if($_GET['menu']="persegi")
        {
            input_persegi();
        } elseif($_GET['menu']="persegi_panjang")
        {
            input_persegi_panjang();
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "==" to equal variable, if just use "=" you give a variable value, so your code must be :

```
<?php
        if($_GET['menu']=="persegi"){
        input_persegi();
        }
        else if($_GET['menu']=="persegi_panjang"){
        input_persegi_panjang();
        }
?>
```

Comment: @GroundHeaven sama-sama

Answer (score 0):

try to print and check the result of `print_r($_GET['menu']);`

Maybe different output when you access another url so it's not match in you if else statment.